# Uninstalled Tor, now can't even get to the site to dl again

Tags: troubleshooting

I was having problems I already asked about (2 Tors in my apps folder and dock), so I decided to uninstall everything and start over. Only today I've been unable to access the Tor site, from any browser (Firefox and Safari) or search engine (Google, Yahoo, Bing). All I get is the spinning wheel and then a can't find the server/problem loading page error message. Tried thru CNET and PCMag and got a TextEdit file. IsItDown tells me repeatedly there's no problem with the site. I have read that ComCast is blocking Tor, but I have Time Warner - are they blocking it too? Is the site under maintenance since it's Sunday? But why wouldn't I then be at least able to get to the site and get a maintenance message?

I fixed it. I had to change my DNS - for some reason the TWC one stopped working - does this mean TWC is blocking Tor? I changed to Google's open DNS. All of a sudden I could access the site and download TBB. Now I have Firefox ESR 24.8, and only one Tor in my apps folder and dock. Yay! For some reason, the Tor icon in the apps folder has the No sign over it, but no matter, it works! Took me quite a while since I'm no techie, but I read somewhere changing the DNS might work, didn't even know what a DNS was, found out I didn't have to change it for my network (my wife would kill me), just for my computer. I still have Tor on my laptop - wonder if I have to change the DNS there too. Anyway, I got it back - I use Tor for privacy, not because I do illegal things, but because I think it's creepy to be followed around and reported on. Big Brother and 1984 and Neuromancer and Snow Crash etc....